# How to convert data to an integer and percentage in RStudio

Tags: r, dplyr

hoping this is an easy question, I am not very familiar with R. I am wanting to create a bar graph showing the 'percentage of drunk people' per state. I was wondering how I can convert the data to an integer and then a percentage. I have tried this function but it did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
as.integer(RBT$Positive.RBT) 
as.integer(RBT$RBT.conducted) 

datapercent = RBT %>% mutate(percentdrinking = Positive.RBT/RBT.conducted*100)
```

When I do this I get the error
Error in mutate()

Comment: Please provide an example of your dataset using `dput(head(RBT))`.

Comment: PLEASE PROVIDE ENTIRE ERROR MESSAGE.

Comment: Also this doesn’t seem to make sense. Why not round  or coerce to integer? Surely there must be earlier questions with answer on ho to format results as percentages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess at what you didn't do. You ran `as.integer(RBT$Positive.RBT)` and `as.integer(RBT$RBT.conducted)` and saw some kind of numeric output in your console, but you did not apply those changes to your data set. To do that, you need to use `=` or `<-` to assign the variable change into your `RBT`.

```r
RBT$Positive.RBT = as.integer(RBT$Positive.RBT) 
RBT$RBT.conducted = as.integer(RBT$RBT.conducted) 

datapercent = RBT %>% mutate(percentdrinking = Positive.RBT/RBT.conducted*100)
```

(Forgetting to do so is a common beginner's mistake.)

Simply running `as.integer(RBT$Positive.RBT)` or `as.integer(RBT$RBT.conducted)` shows you its output but does not store the change into your variable.